# What is the use case for using a JsonResult action in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

When is it typical to use the JsonResult action in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

From where is the JsonResult usually called; from another action or an actionlink rendered in the html?

Can you give me some examples where you want json instead of a typical view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say, for example you wanted to populate a jQuery autocomplete with a list of values based on a selection of another field, so you can't determine the data on page load. I would typically call an action method in a `$.ajax` call, then return an array of items to populate the autocomplete with.

Example, here's my jQuery, one function for the call and another that gets called to populate the automcomplete with received data:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetHomes", "Account")',
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success || data.Success == null) {
                    WireUpHomesData(data);
                } else {
                    ShowErrorDialog();
                }
            }
        });

    ShowDialog();
});

function WireUpHomesData(data) {
    var homes = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        homes[i] = { label: data[i].HomeName, text: data[i].HomeId, icon: data[i].HomeIcon, desc:data[i].HomeAddress };
    }
    $("#home").autocomplete({
            source: homes,
            select: function (event, item) {
                homeUrl = '@Url.Action("Site", "Sites")/' + item.item.text;
            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><span class='" + item.icon + "'/><span class='fs-ui-autocomplete-home'>" + item.value + "</span><br>" + item.desc+ "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    }; 
    $(".ui-autocomplete").addClass("fs-ui-autocomplete");
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetHomes()
{
    return Json(RequiresAclAttribute.HomesForUser());
}
```

And here's the method signature for the method that's called:

```
public IEnumerable<HomeInfo> HomesForUser()
```

And for clarity, here's the `HomeInfo` class:

```
public class HomeInfo
{
    public string HomeId { get; set; }
    public string HomeName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomeIcon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Awesome and very complete answers.  Thanks for the illustration.  Totally filled in the blanks for me.  Seth

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

`JsonResult`  is a subclass derived from `ActionResult` class. You can use this when you want to return a Json object.

```
public JsonResult GetItems()
{
  var jsonResult=new { Id = "23", Name = "Scott"};
  return Json(jsonResult,JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

This will return the same result as

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
  var jsonResult=new { Id = "23", Name = "Scott"};
  return Json(jsonResult,JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Possible use of this is to get some chunk of data in asynchronous way. Ex : Imagine you have a drop down where you are showing the states and when user selects a state, you want to to bring the list of cities belongs to the state and show it in the page without a page refrest. you can call use jQuery ajax /getJson method (short hand of jQuery get with json as datatype) method to get this data from an `ActionMethod` which returns `Json` data.

A small example to call an Action method which returns the Json data

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON('YourController/GetItems', function(data) {
      alert(data.Id);
      alert(data.Name );
   });
});
```

With JsonResult class the response content type will be "`application/json`" if nothing is specified explicitly. Internally The `ExecuteResult` method uses `JavaScriptSerializer`  to Serialize the content when returning data.

Comment: I can't seem to get away from you dude, if I answer a question, you're there, if I'm thinking of answering one, you're there! :P

Comment: @mattytommo: Cool :)  Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

The JsonResult is very usefull wehn making ajax calls from javascript, e.g. using getJSON from jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

The benefit of JsonResult is it returns a JSON formatted result without effort.

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax request from a client script that does not involve a full page load. Basically.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is client side processing and client need that data use jsonresult like in autofill or remote validation